# If $a$ is an element of a group and $|a| = n$ , prove that $ C_G(a)= C_G(a^k)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $a \in G$ and $|a| = n$, prove that $C_G(a)= C_G(a^k)$ where $\gcd(k,n)=1$. $C_G(a)$ refers to centralizer of $a$ in the group $G$.

Attempt : $x \in G$ and $x \in C(a) \iff  a x = xa ........ (1)$

Pre operating by $a^{k-1}$, we get : $a^k x = x a^k ........ (2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ , we get that $C(a) \subseteq C(a^k) ..... (3)$

Now, since, $\gcd(a,k) = 1 \Rightarrow |a^k| = n$ and

$\langle a\rangle =\langle a^k \rangle$.

From here how do  I prove that $C(a^k) \subseteq C(a)$.

So that from $(3)$ and above statement I can conclude that $C(a) = C(a^k)$

Thanks

Comment: Repeat your argument, with $m$ copies of $a^k$, such that $(a^k)^m=a$.

Comment: Thank you. Got the idea that Centralizer of a is always contained in the centralizer of higher powers of k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, for any group $G$ and subset $S \subseteq G$, $C(S) := \bigcap_{s \in S} C(s) = C(\langle S \rangle)$. Since $a, a^k$ generated the same subgroup if $k$ is relatively prime to $|a|$, this gives the result you want.

An interesting question to think about is: what are necessary and sufficient conditions for $C(x) = C(y)$, for any $x, y \in G$? Or more generally, for two subgroups $H$ and $K$, when is $C(H) = C(K)$?